# Please help me translate

Tags: pentateuch-chumash

on the passuk in shemos:

Shemos 8:8
וַיֵּצֵא מֹשֶׁה וְאַהֲרֹן מֵעִם פַּרְעֹה וַיִּצְעַק מֹשֶׁה אֶל־יְהֹוָה עַל־דְּבַר הַצְפַרְדְּעִים אֲשֶׁר־שָׂם לְפַרְעֹה׃

can someone please help translate Rav Samson Hirsch bellow.

ויצעק – ״כדברך״ [בפסוק ו] הייתה התיבה הראשונה שדיבר משה – במסגרת שליחותו – מעצמו ורצונו. הוא העז להסתכן בזה, ואכן עלה בידו. אדם הסופג אל תוכו את עצת ה׳, יחוש בנקל ויאמוד נכון את הישר בעיני ה׳; וה׳ מצדו מקיים את עצת שלוחיו, כמו שנאמר: ״וַעֲצַת מַלְאָכָיו יַשְׁלִים״ (ישעיהו מד, כו). אולם, מכיון שהייתה זאת הבטחתו העצמאית הראשונה, ״צעק״ משה אל ה׳ שיקיים את דברו (של משה).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**And he cried out** - "As you say" [in verse 6] was the first thing that Moshe said – in the context of his mission – of his own will. He took the risk and it paid off. A person who absorbs Hashem's guidance will easily sense and correctly gauge what is right in Hashem's eyes; and Hashem, for His part, upholds the counsel of his messengers, as it is said: "And He fulfills the counsel of His messengers" (Isaiah 44:26). However, since this was his first independent promise, Moshe "cried" to Hashem to keep his (Moshe's) word.